# Excel: How to not count a particular cell on condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I need to calculate a column having many cells but I want to not calculate particular cells on condition. For example:

Scenario:

```
Sr No     Marks
 1           46
 2           33
 3           44
 4           32
 5           11
 6           99
 7           27
 8           98
```

I want to get the sum of marks but only those cells should be added whom marks are more than 50. What formula should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `SUMIF` here:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B9, ">50")
```

This assumes that your `Marks` column is in column `B`, and that the first data point is on the second row.

**Edit:**

If you want to take the average value of marks, where the mark is over 50, then we can also use `COUNTIF`:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B9, ">50") / COUNTIF(B2:B9, ">50")
```

Comment: and if i have to get average? same condtiion. more than 50 should be averaged?

Comment: @TehminaBatool I have updated my answer per your requirements.

Comment: You can also use AVERAGEIF (B2:B9, ">50") for the average of the marks  over 50.

Comment: @JohnF And I think that might be a better option to avoid a possible divide by zero.